# Array like statement for multiple ANDs in an IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

Is there to a way to improve the below? I would like to know if an array-like statement can replace the below.

I just want to like remove the multiple "And Not"s so if you can suggest something to optimize the below then I would appreciate it.

```
    Set ws_raw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw")
    Set ws_master_tracker = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Tracker")
    ' more assignments here...

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Not ws Is ws_raw _
            And Not ws Is ws_master_tracker _
            And Not ws Is ws_title_page _
            And Not ws Is ws_sample _
            And Not ws Is ws_closing _
            And Not ws Is ws_ref _
            And Not ws Is ws_pdf_template _
            And Not ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then

            project_name = ws.Range("E3").Value
            int_last_row_of_ws = 46

            For int_current_row_of_ws = 11 To int_last_row_of_ws
                cell_value = ws.Cells(int_current_row_of_ws, 3).Value

                With rng_raw
                    .AutoFilter 1, project_name
                End With

                Set rng_filtered_raw = ws_raw.Range("J3", ws_raw.Cells(int_last_row_of_raw, int_last_col_of_raw)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                Select Case cell_value

                    Case Is = "Task Creation!"
                        module_to_look_for = "Task Creation"
                    ' twenty more cases

                    ' Others that are manually typed
                    Case Else
                        module_to_look_for = "MANUAL"

                End Select

                If Not rng_filtered_raw Is Nothing Then

                    If module_to_look_for = "MANUAL" Then
                        ' Do nothing
                        ' Highlight cell, etc.
                    Else
                        look_up_result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(module_to_look_for, rng_filtered_raw, 3, False)

                        If look_up_result = "" Then
                            ws.Cells(int_current_row_of_ws, 56).Value = "Blank Date!"
                        Else
                            ws.Cells(int_current_row_of_ws, 56).Value = look_up_result
                        End If
                    End If

                End If

            Next int_current_row_of_ws

        End If

    Next ws
```

Something like:

```
Dim some_array_variable As Array
Set some_array_variable = (ws_master_tracker, ws_title_page, .....)

If Not ws Is In some_array_variable Then
' some code...
```

Please help, I am new in VBA.

Comment: You can create a dictionary of names, although does the code really need optimization? Unless the above statement is executing a large number of times, is it an issue?

Comment: @JohnColeman, I just would like to know my options. how many "AND NOT" lines do I have to make for me to consider using the "dictionary of names" route? Which of the two would be faster?

Comment: Dictionaries have `O(1)` lookup and VBA doesn't short-circuit Boolean operators, so in some sense a dictionary is preferable, but I would be surprised if efficiency is an issue were. Unless you are repeatedly looping over the worksheets, the difference between the approaches might very well be swallowed up by the overhead of creating the dictionary. If efficiency is your only concern, this sounds like a case of premature optimization. I think that readability is the more important criterion here. Pick whichever method best expresses your intent.

Comment: You can use `application.Match` also

Comment: @JohnColeman I prefer readability before anything else. Anyway, I am actually looping over like 30-50 project worksheets. I posted a more complete code above. Do you still think that I should still stick with my original method?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thank you, I will check that out.

Comment: I don't think that you should stick with that, an if statement with 30-50 clauses is far from readable. An even though `Is` might work, it does have a complicated semantics which causes it to not always work as you might expect, whereas a straight name comparison is conceptually clearer

Comment: @JohnColeman I did not say 30-50 clauses within an if statement, it's actually 30-50 worksheets that this "For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets" code needs to be run on. The "AND NOT"s I think will be like around 15.

Comment: I misunderstood. Matters of style are partly matters of taste. What you have isn't all that unreadable by itself, though it seems pointless to have variables like `ws_raw` if their only function is in that condition. An approach using a dictionary or list of forbidden names seems cleaner.

Comment: @John Coleman, thanks for your inputs. I really appreciate it. Now since I am new to VBA I better start learning about dictionaries. Do you mind if I reach out to your email?

Comment: Sorry I think it was a little bit inappropriate to ask but I will keep that in mind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the filter method of an array to check existance:

```
dim arrSheets() as string
arrSheets = Split("sheetNameOne,sheetNameTwo,sheetNameThree", ",")
if ubound(filter(arrsheets,"sheetNameOne"))>-1 then debug.print "Sheet is in list"
```

Edit: extended answer as requested...

I used sheet names for brevity rather than worksheet objects as you just have to list the worksheet names in a comma separated string. To use the actual objects as you have done in your code you'd need to assign them to an array like so;

```
Dim arrSheets(3) as string
arrSheets(0) = ws_master_tracker.name
arrSheets(1) = ws_title_page.name
arrSheets(2) = ws_sample.name
```

Rather than as a string;

```
arrSheets = Split("Master Tracker,Title Page,Sample Sheet", ",")
```

The `Split` method takes a string and splits it into the elements of an array based on a delimiter, in the above example a comma. Think of Text-To-Columns in Excel.

The `Ubound` property describes how many elements are in an array - three in this example. It is zero based i.e. 1 instance will return 0, 2 instances = 1, 3 = 2 and so on.

The `Filter` method returns a new array containing only the elements that match the specified criteria, in this case a specific worksheet name. As Tim Williams commented the method will include substrings, so if you have a sheet called 'my sheet' and one called 'some other sheet' filtering for the word 'sheet' will return both.

Putting them together: `Split` creates the array from the string, filtering returns an array containing the string(s) requested, `Ubound` tells you how many times that string is in the filtered array. If its not present Ubound will return -1, otherwise a number greater than -1.

In your original code this will tell you if a sheet name is one of the names you want to omit. You'd then need to check if that sheet is hidden separately.

```
if ubound(filter(arrsheets,"sheetNameOne"))=-1 then ' the sheet is not in the list
   if sheets("sheetNameOne").Visible = xlSheetHidden Then ' is it hidden?
```

Comment: @JohnColeman Ops, fluffed the syntax from memory, edited now, thanks for spotting

Comment: Note - `Filter` also matches *substrings*, so you need to be careful there.

Comment: @Absinthe I somehow made my code above more complete. I am not familiar with ubound, filter, Split so can this filter method be applied in my code above?

Comment: How can I edit your code to say the other way around? That the sheet is not in the list?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the type of variable you are using.  This tests for primary colors:

```
Sub MultiAND()

    kolor = "mauve"

    If Not kolor = "red" And Not kolor = "blue" And Not kolor = "yellow" Then
        MsgBox "secondary"
    Else
        MsgBox "primary"
    End If
End Sub
```

because the variables are strings, the chain of `AND NOT` can be replaced by:

```
Sub StringMeAlong()
    kolor = " mauve "
    s = " red blue yellow "
    If InStr(s, kolor) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "secondary"
    Else
        MsgBox "primary"
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is a simple prime number test for numbers less than 100:

```
Sub IsItPrime()
    s = "|1|2|3|5|7|11|13|17|19|23|29|31|37|41|43|47|53|59|61|67|71|73|79|83|89|97|"
    N = 23
    v = "|" & CStr(N) & "|"
    If InStr(s, v) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "not prime"
    Else
        MsgBox "Prime"
    End If
End Sub
```

If this was in a worksheet formula, you could use the `MATCH()` function with array constants.

Comment: Hi Gary, I edited my code above. My variables are worksheets, can we still somehow use InStr?